# UserWarning: Module matplotlib was already imported

Tags: python, matplotlib

I get the following warning whenever running a script:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mpl_toolkits/__init__.py:2: UserWarning: Module matplotlib was already imported from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc, but /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6 is being added to sys.path
  __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Here is the imports section of the script:

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as Canvas
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick, plot_day_summary
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axes_size import AxesY
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.parasite_axes import SubplotHost
from matplotlib import rcParams
```

What is causing the warning?

Comment: I get a similar error when running your code, except that it is complaining about the module `readline` already being imported. The line which was causing troubles was `from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid import make_axes_locatable`

Answer (score 9):

The "problem" is with your installation of matplotlib - or rather, your two installations of it - not with the program you're trying to run.

From the message, I can infer that you have one version of matplotlib installed in /usr/local - perhaps a newer version that you installed yourself without using OS package management? - and another version in the OS standard location, /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6.

The warning message tells you that Python *noticed* the OS packaged version, but it is going to ignore it (ie, not load any modules from it) because it *already* found the version in /usr/local and it can't make sense of having modules from two different directories.

If you meant to have two versions and you meant to be using the version in /usr/local, then the warning is essentially harmless to you.

If you didn't realize you have two versions of matplotlib installed, you might want to try to clean up that situation a bit.